# Optimizing Performance of Highly Nested Postgres SQL Query

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have been working with a PostgreSQL database and I've encountered a SQL query that seems to have a high degree of nesting, which I suspect might be impacting its performance. I'm seeking advice on how to optimize this query for better efficiency.

As an example dataset, consider the following tables and data:

1. `params` with columns:

   - `group_id` (integer)
   - `params_type` (ENUM ['SCHOOL_DATA', 'PEOPLE_DATA', 'GEO_DATA', 'REPORT_DATA'])
   - `calculated_values` (jsonb)
2. `params_groups` with columns:

   - `id` (integer)
   - `school_id` (integer)
   - `created_at` (timestamp)

**Example rows for `params` table:**

| group_id | params_type | calculated_values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SCHOOL_DATA | {"name": "School A", "status": "Private"} |
| 1 | PEOPLE_DATA | {"staffCount": 9, "studentsCount": 80} |
| 1 | GEO_DATA | {"country": "USA", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 1 | REPORT_DATA | {"gradesAvgs": {"math": 76, "physics": 80, "history": 78} "USA", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 2 | SCHOOL_DATA | {"name": "School B", "status": "Private"} |
| 2 | PEOPLE_DATA | {"staffCount": 15, "studentsCount": 130} |
| 2 | GEO_DATA | {"country": "Brazil", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 2 | REPORT_DATA | {"gradesAvgs": {"math": 88, "physics": 83, "history": 83} "Brazil", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 3 | SCHOOL_DATA | {"name": "School C", "status": "Public"} |
| 3 | PEOPLE_DATA | {"staffCount": 40, "studentsCount": 245} |
| 3 | GEO_DATA | {"country": "France", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 3 | REPORT_DATA | {"gradesAvgs": {"math": 92, "physics": 86, "history": 90} "France", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 4 | SCHOOL_DATA | {"name": "School D", "status": "Private"} |
| 4 | PEOPLE_DATA | {"staffCount": 13, "studentsCount": 100} |
| 4 | GEO_DATA | {"country": "India", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 4 | REPORT_DATA | {"gradesAvgs": {"math": 81, "physics": 74, "history": 71} "India", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 5 | SCHOOL_DATA | {"name": "School E", "status": "Public"} |
| 5 | PEOPLE_DATA | {"staffCount": 25, "studentsCount": 180} |
| 5 | GEO_DATA | {"country": "USA", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |
| 5 | REPORT_DATA | {"gradesAvgs": {"math": 90, "physics": 84, "history": 78} "USA", "state": "XX", "street": "..."} |

**Example rows for `params_groups` table:**

| id | school_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 2023-08-15 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 102 | 2023-08-14 10:30:00 |
| 3 | 101 | 2023-08-14 15:45:00 |
| 4 | 103 | 2023-08-13 11:20:00 |
| 5 | 102 | 2023-08-13 14:10:00 |

Here's the query in question:

```sql
SELECT
    params.group_id AS params_group_id
FROM
    params
WHERE
    params.group_id IN (
        SELECT
            params.group_id
        FROM
            params
        WHERE
            params.group_id IN (
                SELECT
                    params.group_id
                FROM
                    params
                WHERE
                    params.group_id IN (
                        SELECT
                            params.group_id
                        FROM
                            params
                        WHERE
                            params.group_id IN (
                                -- Make sure we get the latest group of params per school in case a school has multiple params groups created in different time
                                SELECT
                                    DISTINCT ON (params_groups.school_id) params_groups.id
                                FROM
                                    params_groups
                                ORDER BY
                                    params_groups.school_id,
                                    params_groups.created_at DESC
                            )
                            AND params.params_type = 'REPORT_DATA'
                            AND (
                                params.calculated_values @> '{"math": 90}'
                            )
                    )
                    AND params.params_type = 'PEOPLE_DATA'
                    AND CAST(
                        (
                            params.calculated_values ->> 'headcount'
                        ) AS INTEGER
                    ) <= 25
            )
            AND params.params_type = 'SCHOOL_DATA'
            AND (
                params.calculated_values @> '{"status": "Private"}'
            )
    )
    AND params.params_type = 'GEO_DATA'
    AND (
        params.calculated_values @> '{"country": "USA"}'
    )
LIMIT
    10000
```

Obviously I cannot use all of the different filters in a single WHERE with AND operator between them because a row can never be of `params_type = X` and `params_type = Y` simultaneously

I suspect that the repeated subqueries and nested conditions might be causing a performance bottleneck. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to optimize this query to make it more efficient. Perhaps there's a way to achieve the same result with fewer nested levels or using different SQL techniques?

Thank you for your insights and expertise!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)